# Binding angularjs inside leaflet path message

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angularjs

I am trying to bind angular attributes inside to angular leaflet directive's path message.But I couldn't do it.my code is below. As you see, it doesn't apear my $scope value.

```
 $scope.pth = {
        p1: {
            color: '#0ff',
            weight: 8,
            latlngs: [
                { lat: 48.83, lng: 2.37 },
                { lat: 41.91, lng: 12.48 }
            ],  message:"hello worldv  {{a}}",
            getMessageScope: function () { return $scope; },
        }
    }
    $scope.a="{{2+3}}";
```

you can click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/49xVW/33/) to look at my code.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?